# Poisson regression - How to check mean = variance assumption when the counts have different exposures?

Tags: r, assumptions, poisson-regression

I'm modeling rate data using Poisson regression and I want to assess the model assumption of mean = variance. I understand that for Poisson regression it's the conditional means that equal the conditional variances for different levels of the predictor variables.

Suppose below is some random example data from one of those combinations of predictor variables that shows the counts (x) and the exposure:

```
n = 100

dat = data.frame(
  x = rpois(n, 3)
  exposure = runif(n, min = 10, max = 50)
)
```

My question is how do I account for the varying levels of exposure when checking this assumption?

Comment: Your problem is that your "response" in this case is a derived value, the rate given by $x / \text{exposure}$. In a Poisson regression, the exposure is handled by an offset `glm(x ~ <variables> + offset(log(exposure)), family=poisson)`. When you verify the assumptions, the exposure is on the RHS of the formula and so doesn't affect sensitivity analyses.

Comment: So is there anything I would do in this case to check this assumption besides calculating the mean and variance of the raw counts by the non-offset variables? Or just like what is done here? https://bookdown.org/roback/bookdown-BeyondMLR/ch-poissonreg.html

Comment: Some discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40385/poisson-regression-assumptions-and-how-to-test-them-in-r I think the consensus is that there is no omnibus for checking GLM assumptions. If you're worried, you can fit a quasipoisson model instead (just add "quasi" to the "poisson" in the family statement). And you're done!

Comment: @ScottWhite have a look at the R package `DHARMa`. It requires you to read a bit of theory but it is an excellent tool for diagnosing and assessing GLMs. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Comment: Thanks @AlexJ. I'll take a look at that. Things are looking pretty good so far when I look at the data from a negative binomial lens right now, but I still have a stuck thought on the exposure variable. So still looking around until things click.

Comment: Would an AIC and `DHARMa` comparison e.g. `mdl1 <- glm(x ~ 1, family = poisson(), data = dat); mdl2 <- glm(x ~ 1 + offset(log(exposure)), family = poisson(), data = dat)` solve your problem? Certainly in the dummy example you give, both AIC and `DHARMa` suggest not including an exposure term.